# XPath Child Contents

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the contents of the paragraph of the following html:

```
 <h4 class="m-b-0 text-dark synopsis"><p>This is the text I want.</p></h4>
```

There's several `h4`s, but only one with the class `synopsis`.

I'm able to get the h4 element with `print_r($xpath->query("//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]"));` but I'm unable to get the child paragraph contents.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<h4>` cannot contain a `<p>` element. Fix that first.

Comment: Try using `evaluate`: `print_r($xpath->evaluate("//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]/p"))`

Answer (score 2):

`h4` can not contain `p`. PHPs DOMDocument will try to fix the HTML:

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML(
  '<h4 class="m-b-0 text-dark synopsis"><p>This is the text I want.</p></h4>',
);
echo $document->saveHTML();
```

```html
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : h4 in Entity, line: 1 in /in/BTVAZ on line 4
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><h4 class="m-b-0 text-dark synopsis"></h4><p>This is the text I want.</p></body></html>
```

This can be mostly avoided with some loading flags:

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML(
  '<h4 class="m-b-0 text-dark synopsis"><p>This is the text I want.</p></h4>',
  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOERROR
);
echo $document->saveHTML();
```

```html
<h4 class="m-b-0 text-dark synopsis"><p>This is the text I want.</p></h4>
```

The class attribute value consists of tokens separated by whitespace. A simple `contains()` will match the string if it is part of another class name.

To match them with Xpath 1.0, use `normalize-space()` and `concat()`. The idea is to convert the attribute value to `{space}classOne{space}classTwo{space}` and match them against `{space}classOne{space}`.

- Replace all white space sequences with a single space and trim the value.
  `normalize-space(@class)`.
- Add a spaces at start/end:
  `concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' ')`
- Look for class name surrounded by space:
  `[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' synopsis ')]`
- Match any element node with the class:
  `//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' synopsis ')]`
- Cast first node to string:
  `string(//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' synopsis ')])`

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML(
  '<h4 class="m-b-0 text-dark synopsis"><p>This is the text I want.</p></h4>',
  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOERROR
);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = "string(//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' synopsis ')])";

var_dump($xpath->evaluate($expression));
```

Output:

```
string(24) "This is the text I want."
```

If you try to fetch multiple nodes, remove the string cast in Xpath. The expression will return a node list. Iterate the nodes and read the `$textContent` property. It will contain the contents of all descendant text nodes.

```
$expression = "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' synopsis ')]";

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $synopsis) {
    var_dump($synopsis->textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is correct at the XML level, but OP's real problem arose due to php/libxml's attempt to repair the validity constrain violation that disallows a `p` element within a `h4`.  See [@ThW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76118379/290085) (+1) for further details.*

---

If

```
//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]
```

selects the desired `h4` elements, then

```
//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]/p
```

will select the children `p` elements of the desired `h4` elements, and

```
//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]/p/text()
```

will select the text node children of those `p` elements.

You can obtain the string value of a node via `string()`:

```
string(//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]/p)
```

Note that the above assumes **XPath 1.0** (or that there will only be one such `p`), where the string value of the first node of the node set selected by `//h4/p` will be returned.  Passing a sequence of nodes to `string()` would be an error in **XPath 2.0 and higher**, where instead you should use:

```
string((//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]/p)[0])
```

if there could be more than one such `p`, or

```
//h4[contains(@class, 'synopsis')]/p/string()
```

if you'd like the string values of all such `p` elements returned.

---

### Example HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>p is not allowed in h4...</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h4><p>...but can still be selected via XPath</p></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

### XPath selection example

```
$x("//h4/p")
[p]
$x("string(//h4/p)")
'...but can still be selected via XPath'
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid.

Comment: @Rob with the <p> nestled in the <h4> will that prevent XPath from returning any content? I don't control the html, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @GFL I never deal with broken markup so I wouldn't know.

Comment: @kjhughes libxml does care about validity and will try to fix the document.

Comment: @ThW: So while XPath would not care about validity, libxml does and tries to correct.  Very interesting.  I stand corrected.   Thank you for pointing this out.